# Limiting shell commands that a user can run over SSH

Tags: permissions, ssh, amazon-ec2

I would like to setup up an isolated AWS EC2 Linux server which has 2 different users:

1) Data Owner: Can upload CSV file to this server from specific IP address. We can create an unrestricted user for this user.

2) Programmer: Programmer shall access to the EC2 server via SSH and run a python script which can access to the CSV file uploaded by Data Owner. However, we would like to make sure that the programmer can not copy the file out of the EC2 server.

The programmer also needs to upload & update his own python script regularly. (from a specific IP address). We can assume the python script to be safe (which we will inspect before executing).
I will appreciate if you can guide me who to configure this EC2 server (ie: security groups, shell commands etc).

Comment: Accessing a file but not copy is not really possible. Why won't you just let the owner run the python script the programmer delivers?

Comment: The programmer needs to see the result. And this is an iterative process.

Comment: Then let the programmer trigger the execution, the execution is then done by the owner, the output is readable by the programmer.

Comment: The programmer needs to see the result immediately. The owner needs some kind of automation for that. I thought developing an API for that but the programmer can place a code that can access the file and download it in the python script. And the programmer still needs to upload & update his own python script regularly.